# How can I get last segment of the string?

Tags: php, regex

**Summery:**

I need to get last part of this string:

```
$str = 'http://localhost:8000/news/786425/fa';
//                              last part ^^
```

How can I do that?

---

**Explanation:**

I'm trying to either add a language in the end of URL *(if it isn't exist)* or replace it with `en` *(if a language already exists)*. My website supports only two languages: `en`, `fa`. So just `en` and `fa` should be detected as languages. In other word, they are allowed languages, anything else would considered as a URL's parameter.

---

**Examples:**

```
$str = 'http://localhost:8000/news/786425/fa';
// expected output: http://localhost:8000/news/786425/en

 $str = 'http://localhost:8000/news/786425';
// expected output: http://localhost:8000/news/786425/en

 $str = 'http://localhost:8000/news/786425/pg';  // pg is not defined as a language
// expected output: http://localhost:8000/news/786425/pg/en


 $str = 'http://localhost:8000/news/786425/en';
// expected output: http://localhost:8000/news/786425/en
```

---

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/KgOe7y/2) is what I've tried so far.

Comment: Noted that I can `explode()` the string per `/` and then use the last item of the array, but I like to do that by regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the last portion that does not contain `/`:

```
[^\/]+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K80Oy8/1)

---

To match `en`/`fa` only:

```
(?=(?:en|fa)$)[^\/]+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K80Oy8/3)

---

Or a negative lookahead:

```
(?!\/)(?:en|fa)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K80Oy8/4)

Comment: Yes it almost works .. but as I've mentioned in the question, I need to use both `en` and `fa` in the pattern literally. Something like this: `\/(?:en|fa)$`

Comment: upvote anyway *(because this solution answers **summery** part of my question)*.